# Combine: Listen to internal collection changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have a data manager that encapsulates a collection of objects. I want to listen to changes in that manager, as well as changes in collection objects. I came up with the solution using `PassthroughSubject` and `sink`, but I am pretty new to Combine and wondering is it correct and is there a better way to do that.

```
import Combine

class Item {
  var data = false {
    didSet {
      self.subject.send()
    }
  }
  let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

}

class DataManager {
  private(set) var items = [Item]() {
    didSet {
      self.subject.send()
    }
  }
  let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

  func addItem(_ item: Item) {
    self.items.append(item)
    item.subject.sink { [weak self] in
      self?.subject.send()
    }
  }
}

var item = Item()
var manager = DataManager()
manager.subject.sink {
  print("Received Update")
}
manager.addItem(item) // Received Update
item.data = false // Received Update
item.data = true // Received Update
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the stored items, making them all structures should work. Arrays are structures, so will trigger the didSet when changed. Structures inside of arrays should change the value of the array and cause didSet to trigger for the array. Classes will not because the reference value of the class never changes. The current stance is that you should use structures over classes unless you have a good reason to use a class. Swift [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) for more info.

The other option is to do what you are already doing and make all of the classes conform to some protocol like `BindableObject`, then monitor `didChange` for each object.

Currently though you are not handling cancelation when an item is removed from the array. You should `subscribe` the `didChange` of `DataManager` to the `didChange` of every element. Then take the resultant `AnyCancellable` and add it to a dictionary keyed under the the item. Then once that item is removed from the array you should remove the associated `AnyCancellable` which will cancel the subscription.

Answer (score 1):

For the newest version of `SwiftUI`, I will pass down the `objectWillChange.send` function to each item in the `@Published` array. Then, for each property of each item, I will call the update handler in the `willSet` property change handler.

Here's an example:

```swift
import Combine

final class User {
    let prepareForUpdate: (() -> Void)?

    var name: String {
        willSet {
            prepareForUpdate?()
        }
    }

    init(prepareForUpdate: (() -> Void)? = nil, name: String) {
        self.prepareForUpdate = prepareForUpdate
        self.name = name
    }
}

final class UserStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User]

    init(_ users: [User] = []) {
        self.users = users
    }

    func addUser(name: String) {
        // Pass in our objectWillChange.send to the User object to listen for updates
        let user = User(prepareForUpdate: objectWillChange.send, name: name)
        users.append(user)
        return user
    }
}
```

Using this method, the view will be updated whenever a `User` in the `users` array is changed.

Comment: Not sure this is the best approach, In the real world the data will come from the backend, how will it work with Codable?